# Center div vertically without overflowing when content is larger

Tags: css, sass

When there's not a lot of content it is centered, but when I have more content it crops and the beginning of modal is not visible.

If I don't use **position absolute** everything is OK, but then if I have less content it's not centered

[image]

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: auto;
  background: purple;
}

.modal {
  max-width: 528px;
  padding: 24px 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(193, 192, 196, 0.35);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="modal">
      i want to be vertically centered, but when i have lot of content i dont want to get cropped on top
      i want to be vertically centered, but when i have lot of content i dont want to get cropped on top
      i want to be vertically centered, but when i have lot of content i dont want to get cropped on top
      i want to be vertically centered, but when i have lot of content i dont want to get cropped on top
      i want to be vertically centered, but when i have lot of content i dont want to get cropped on top
      i want to be vertically centered, but when i have lot of content i dont want to get cropped on top
      i want to be vertically centered, but when i have lot of content i dont want to get cropped on top
      i want to be vertically centered, but when i have lot of content i dont want to get cropped on top
      i want to be vertically centered, but when i have lot of content i dont want to get cropped on top
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```